# WordPress > using wp_insert_category() to separate "category_nicename" from category slug or "cat_name"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to use wp_insert_category() to create a category that's displayed as "My Category" but has a category slug of "test-my-category".

Can I do this with wp_insert_category? Anyone have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Do the following:

```
$category = array('cat_name'=>'My Category', 'category_nicename'=>'test-my-category');
wp_insert_category($category);
```

cat_name is used for the title of the category whilst category_nicename is used for the slug.

[Function Reference:wp insert category « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_category)

Answer (score 2):

```
$parent_term = term_exists( 'fruits', 'product' ); // array is returned if taxonomy is given
$parent_term_id = $parent_term['term_id']; // get numeric term id
wp_insert_term(
  'Apple', // the term 
  'product', // the taxonomy
  array(
    'description '=> 'A yummy apple.'
    'slug' => 'apple'
    'parent'=> $parent_term_id
  )
);
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term

Initial Taxonomies include: 'category', 'post_tag', 'nav_menu', 'link_category' (defined in wp-includes/taxonomy.php)