# In wordpress Can I add a new Category using PHP in my theme

Tags: php, wordpress

So basically I am writing a new wordpress theme, Usually i add a new category in wordpress using the admin panel by filling in some info: "name" and the "slug".

> I want to do this in my theme by overriding the funtions.php file

For example creating a new category named :  **New category** , with the slug **new_category** .
**Is it possible ?**

And of course, I know that this idea doesn't exactly follow some theme programming guidelines such as envato guideline or the Wordpress.org publishers guideline. And yes the best thing would be to make a plugin for this. But here I am talking about a practical point of view, So is it possible? could you just point me up in the right direction (maybe a link to some doc or so?).

Comment: You want when theme installing then create categories?

Comment: Hi @Coder, Thanks for replying. I was thinking to check if the category exists if no I add it, unfortunately I don't have any idea of how to do this programmatically maybe you have some useful docs?

Comment: Please check this link, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59238/how-can-i-get-category-id-by-category-name. If its not work for you then update me

Comment: @Coder, nice link it does tell me how to check if my category exists However i couldn't find something related to how to add this new category. So should I hammer in with some "Insert " SQL? or maybe is there a wordpress function that enable us to add and publish categories on the Wordpress PHP framework?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647917/wordpress-using-wp-insert-category-to-separate-category-nicename-from-cate please follow this link

Comment: From first link you can check the category exist and the last link you can insert category

Comment: Woah @Coder That solves the puzzle man , Thanks a lot. I got things figured out thanks to you :).

Comment: Welcome man. if any type of issue just update me. I am here

Comment: @Coder  thanks man ended up writing some lines with regard to your comments. Shared the code down below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Coder comments I wrote this code that works like a charm for me :

```
$mycat_name = 'New category'; //The name of category that I want to add
$mycat_slug = 'new-category'; //The slug (no spaces, lower-cases)
$mycat = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM $wpdb->terms AS t
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'category' AND t.name = '" . $mycat_name . "'");
$checking = sizeof($mycat) ;

//found out that size is 0 if there the category doesn't exist
if ($checking === 0){
$category = array('cat_name'=>$mycat_name, 'category_nicename'=>$mycat_slug);
wp_insert_category($category);
}
```

So this works and you an just add it anywhere (maybe index.php) , also this wil require you to add the following function that I got from wordpress taxonomy file

```
  function wp_insert_category( $catarr, $wp_error = false ) {
    $cat_defaults = array(
        'cat_ID'               => 0,
        'taxonomy'             => 'category',
        'cat_name'             => '',
        'category_description' => '',
        'category_nicename'    => '',
        'category_parent'      => '',
    );
    $catarr       = wp_parse_args( $catarr, $cat_defaults );

    if ( trim( $catarr['cat_name'] ) == '' ) {
        if ( ! $wp_error ) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return new WP_Error( 'cat_name', __( 'You did not enter a category name.' ) );
        }
    }

    $catarr['cat_ID'] = (int) $catarr['cat_ID'];

    // Are we updating or creating?
    $update = ! empty( $catarr['cat_ID'] );

    $name        = $catarr['cat_name'];
    $description = $catarr['category_description'];
    $slug        = $catarr['category_nicename'];
    $parent      = (int) $catarr['category_parent'];
    if ( $parent < 0 ) {
        $parent = 0;
    }

    if ( empty( $parent )
        || ! term_exists( $parent, $catarr['taxonomy'] )
        || ( $catarr['cat_ID'] && term_is_ancestor_of( $catarr['cat_ID'], $parent, $catarr['taxonomy'] ) ) ) {
        $parent = 0;
    }

    $args = compact( 'name', 'slug', 'parent', 'description' );

    if ( $update ) {
        $catarr['cat_ID'] = wp_update_term( $catarr['cat_ID'], $catarr['taxonomy'], $args );
    } else {
        $catarr['cat_ID'] = wp_insert_term( $catarr['cat_name'], $catarr['taxonomy'], $args );
    }

    if ( is_wp_error( $catarr['cat_ID'] ) ) {
        if ( $wp_error ) {
            return $catarr['cat_ID'];
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return $catarr['cat_ID']['term_id'];
    }
```

Works for me, a Quick and dirty way to push gategories in your thee directly.

From a practical point (this is good) but still a bad idea with regards to wordpress publishers guidelines where this code must at least be in a plugin.